# reading and writing tabular text files in python3

Tags: python, file, python-3.x, tabular

I have several tabular text files in a folder.The data in the first column are strings,second and third column integers.How can I read them all in and write the first column and the second column edited(say divided by two) into a new tabular text file? I've just begun learning python so please kindly give example code if possible.Thanks.

Comment: for processing tabular files use `csv` library

Answer (score 2):

This snippet might give you some idea

```
# terrible code for educational purposes only!

in_stream = open(filename_in)
out_stream = open(filename_out, 'w')
output = csv.writer(out_stream)

for col_string, col_value1, col_value2 in csv.reader(in_stream):
    new_row = [col_string, col_value1 / 2, col_value2]
    output.write(new_row)
```

Comment: Nice code for a novice! I'm reading in several files so I shall use 'a' parameter while  reading the 2nd and 3rd.. files ,right? Do 'col_string' and 'col_value's claim themselves automatically or do I have to claim them?

Comment: `open(f, 'a')` would append new lines to the old file. Also in python you don not need declare variables, not delete them (this is what the garbage collector is paid for)

Comment: i put the code into a script and ran it in cmd. an error occurred on the "for col_string" line: ValueError need more than 1 value to unpack. google says it seems to be a cmd line parameter problem.how can i fix it?

Comment: my command is "python.exe tabulario.py". what's the proper command?